# c# methods declaring variables

Tags: c#, methods

i am making a class in which i have used method .they variables are declared directly in method paramter.why i cant declare int below like string.

```
class studentinfoget
{
    static void Getstudnetinformation(string firstname, string lastname, string birthday, string address, int cellnumber, int homenumber)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter your first name");
        firstname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter your LAST NAME");
        lastname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter your brithday ");
        birthday = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter birthday");
        address = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter address");
        cellnumber = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter adress");


    }
```

Error for this code is

> CS0029  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: The error is because, you are typing string and trying to assign this to the int i.e cellnumber. You can use tryPrase before assigning

Comment: Moreover, you probably don't want to store a phone number as an integer. (800)555-1212 is not an integer, but a string.

Comment: Like @ToddSprang says. Just because a field seems like it is usually numbers, does not mean that is the best type for it. Some examples with postal codes come to mind. There would **almost** be no point in using an int if you aren't using it in a more mathematical sense, which should be the case with phone numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `int.TryParse()` to convert the input into an integer.

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cellnumber);
```

However, if the test fails, `cellnumber` will be 0.

A cell number may not necessarily be an integer though - you could have somebody entering the cell number as `"XXX-XXX XXXX"`, or it may have more than 10 digits, in which case you may exceed the `int.MaxValue` of 2,147,483,647. Also, the starting digit might be a 0, which would then be stripped out when stored and render the phone number invalid.

In this case I would recommend storing the value as a string as at least then the user-entered format will be preserved.

Comment: @DrewJordan i tend to build up my explanations as I go, editing and re-editing it until I am happy.

Comment: no worries. Got a +1 from me, this is the best answer here now as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @user1666620 thanks love your answer great concept thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

`cellnumber` is declared as an `int` but `Console.ReadLine` returns a `string`. You need to convert the entered text to a number:

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cellnumber);
```

`TryParse` is used to handle invalid input - if the user enters `Phone` or something that isn't a number `TryParse` won't throw an exception, it will return `false` but execution will continue.

Comment: thansk dave between i got it, (out cellnumber) . out is used for what purpose

Comment: It causes the variable to be passed as reference and doesn't require the variable to be initialized. You can [read more about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx).

Comment: cellnumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); this code can also work like the above example :) its right too i think

Comment: @ahmedshah you are correct, however check my edit for why `TryParse` is probably a better option.

Answer (score 0):

you may use 
`cellnumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

but you should change **cellnumber** and **homenumber** to string variable.

Comment: This answer is confusing at best... It's good that you showed how to parse (although TryParse would be better considering it's just console input) and then you mention using them as strings.

Comment: @DrewJordan what I am trying to say in 2nd part is he should not use int cellnumber rather use string cellnumber

Comment: But *why* should a string be used?